# Facebook like button displays under content when clicked

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I have tried implementing a facebook like button on my website however when the like button is clicked the facebook content displays underneath my website content, specifically any images. Is there a way to correct this?

festrags.com 
Password="cheaye"

Comment: I am not sure why I am being downvoted. I am not trying to get likes as my website is not live to the public unless you have the above password. I am just trying to fix this issue. Please comment if you want more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a unnecessary `z-index: 8888;`

```
.product .image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 8888;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```

Lower it or add this to your CSS (below the above CSS):

```
.fb_iframe_widget_lift {
   z-index: 8889 !important;
}
```

(downvotes might be caused by you not posting any code)

Comment: Thank you for the help ill make the tweak and see if it works! I understand about the code but didn't know what part was relevant to post!!!

Comment: @NeverPhased if it doesn't work add `!important` behind it, it's in the edit